# Dual Boot, Won't Recognize Windows in Bios Or Grub

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

**This is not a grub problem... This is a bios problem

I have an Acer Aspire A515-55G running a dual boot with Win10 and Ubuntu 20.04. For whatever reason, after using Timeshift to restore my machine, the Windows10 bootloader disappeared from grub AND BIOS.

I have tried virtually grub solution on the web, including LiveCD boot-repair, Rescatux, SuperGrub2Beta, manually adding a windows option in sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom.

It seems that all of the aforementioned solutions, requires Windows to at least be present in the bios to work effectively.

When I enter my Bios, -only ubuntu- is listed as a boot option. When I am inside ubuntu, I navigate via nautilus to my windows partition and mount it.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can get Windows back into the bios / grub?

I am running both OS in AHCI, secure boot disabled, fast boot, disabled, & boot UEFI (no other boot modes available.)

This is my last boot-repair pastebin

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GtGggbD9sS/

Finally, my windows rescue USB, says that it can't repair my boot. Does any know how to repair my boot using the windows command prompt that I can reach when I boot from usb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boot the machine using a Windows USB key, go to "command prompt", enter (separately):

`bootrec.exe /fixmbr`
`bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd`

reboot && allow Windows to scan / repair the drive.

login into windows and make sure everything is working.

reboot and enter bios as necessary disable: fast boot & secure boot, then select ubuntu as the first boot disk, exit bios.

Boot into ubuntu and run `os-prober` which should successfully locate the new repaired windows partiition.

Then run `update-grub` and reboot.

Windows should be back in the grub menu. :-)